# Android ConstraintLayout: View overlap when constraint to the bottom of a horizontal chain

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I wanna `view3` directly below `view1` and `txt1` with no gap.

The text value of `txt1` is dynamic at runtime. When `txt1` takes multiple lines, all views are correct. **But when `txt1` takes only one line, `view1` and `view3` overlap.**

**Also I wanna use only ConstraitLayout, do not use LinearLayout or other layouts inner ConstraintLayout. And only modify in XML not in Java/Kotlin code**

How can I fix it? Thank you!!

[image: view1 and view3 ovelap when txt1 takes one line]

[image: all views are correct]

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--other views-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/txt1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:text="lorem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view1"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt1"
        />
    <!--other views-->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhhh .. here is the scenario where barrier comes into the picture

Kindly check more detail about barrier in this link

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Barrier

and here is the code that you can use

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--other views-->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/txt1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:text="lorem"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view1"
        />

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
             android:id="@+id/barrier"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             app:barrierDirection=“bottom”
             app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1,txt1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
        />
    <!--other views-->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```